# Check angular form dirty state based on value

Tags: angularjs, validation, angular-ngmodel

I have a simple angular form, like in this [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/nnt6oh?p=preview).

js:

```
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('AppController', function($scope) {
  $scope.values = {
    value: 'default'
  }; 
});
```

html:

```
<form name="form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="input">Value</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="values.value">
  </div>
  <pre>form.$dirty = {{form.$dirty}};</pre>
</form>
```

I want to track dirty of my from and set form state to pristine when values returned back to original.

Is there a way to say angular that this is an original value, and form dirty only with values that not equal this one?

In my example I want to see `from.$dirty = true` when user types something and then enter `default` back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is no another solutions I have written the following directive which allow to to do it declarative way.

directive:

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('trackValue', function() {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(s, e, a, ngModelCtrl) {
      ngModelCtrl.$setOriginalValue = function(value) {
        ngModelCtrl.$originalValue = angular.copy(value);
      }
      ngModelCtrl.$parsers.push(function(value) {
        if(angular.equals(value, ngModelCtrl.$originalValue)) {
          ngModelCtrl.$setPristine();
        }
        return value;
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Then you can save value and changes into form should be compared with it.

```
$scope.form.value.$setOriginalValue($scope.values.value);
```

I've updated [my plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Adgpak?p=preview) where I got desired behavior with this directive. You can change input value to anything, but when you type `default` again, input state will be reset to pristine

Answer (score 0):

You can write something like this:

```
$scope.$watch('values.value', function (newValue) {
    if (newValue === 'some-default-value) {
         this.formName.$setPristine();
    }
}
```

Comment: I am looking for a more common way to do it. How can I do it when I have more than 10 fields like this? I appreciate a special directive for it.